# I need make a weighted average using two matrix

Tags: python, numpy, average

I am not a programmer, I am biologist and I need made the following with two matrix:

```
matrix_de_pesos= np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[0.4, 0.5, 0.6],[0.7, 0.8, 0.9]])
matrix_de_embeddings= np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,20,30]])
```

One matrix contain weights and another embeddings. I need multiply each element of each column of the matrix of weights by each column of the matrix embedding. Then make the sum of the vectors and divide between the total of column of the matrix of embeddings.

I do this in the way:

```
n=[]
for j in range(matrix_de_pesos.shape[1]):
    auxiliar = np.zeros((matrix_de_embeddings.shape[0], matrix_de_embeddings.shape[1]))
    for i in range(matrix_de_pesos.shape[0]):
        for x in range(matrix_de_embeddings.shape[0]):
            auxiliar[x][i] = matrix_de_pesos[i][j]*matrix_de_embeddings[x][i]
    resultado = np.sum(auxiliar,axis=1)/auxiliar.shape[1]
    n.append(resultado)
matrix_final = np.array(n)
matrix_final = matrix_final.T
print(matrix_final)
```

The result is:

```
[[ 1.   1.2  1.4]
 [ 2.2  2.7  3.2]
 [ 3.4  4.2  5. ]
 [10.  12.  14. ]]
```

My code work good for this little matrix, but when I used it for the matrix that I should do it, (of this shapes: weights`(55097, 15677)`, embeddings`(300, 55132)`), the code is very very slow. 
I try do it this whith the function `np.average`, but I do'nt get that the code works. 
I need any solution.
Thank you very much in advance for all.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example @Yaiza ?

Comment: @Yaiza, you can consider numba http://numba.pydata.org/ as well by thinking of parallelism etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Matrix Multiplication

```
import numpy as np
print(np.matmul(matrix_de_embeddings,matrix_de_pesos)/matrix_de_embeddings.shape[1])
```

[Numpy Matrix Multiplication](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)

Comment: Ah great! This is indeed a matmul thinking about it twice. Great answer...

Comment: @yatu I saw your post, After then I learnt about broadcasting so thank you for that.